# Vimrc settings to emulate Sublime's parenthesis auto-completion

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

How do I emulate Sublime text's auto complete behavior for curly braces `{}` on vim? Basically, when a parenthesis is opened, it should auto close in the same line, and when `<CR>` is pressed the cursor should go to the next line with a block indentation and `}` should fall in line with the original indention of the line containing the `{`. If my question is not clear, this is the default behavior of most code editors when dealing with `{}`.

Answer (score 5):

The [Automatically append closing characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) page on the Vim Tips Wiki has everything from simplistic mappings to complete plugin solutions. There seem to be issues with the latest Vim 7.4 version, though.

Answer (score 1):

There exist many plugins with similar features as Ingo pointed out.

[lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), that I'm maintaining, has the features you describe:

- `{` inserts `{}` and moves the cursor in between (and also inserts a placeholder after the closing bracket
- hitting `<cr>` while within a pair of curly-brackets will insert another newline in-between (and indent correctly)

Comment: Does it fully work with the latest Vim 7.4? The warning on the Wiki page is pretty dismal and frightning. Emphasizing this there would be a great selling point for your plugin. (I'm still mainly using Vim 7.3, but not because of that.)

Comment: I'm using vim7.4, compiled from trunk, on several machines. (7.4.192 on one, 7.4.110 on another one). I've no troubles with this plugin of mine. However, it doesn't support redo/undo and it relies on a old placeholder way of doing things.

Comment: EDIT: OK I see the issue with vim7.4. My plugin has never supported undo/redo. As such, it still works perfectly with vim 7.4.